# How to change the textcolor or queryhint textcolor of an Android SearchView in AndroidX?

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview, androidx

The Android searchview has default queryhint textcolor and text color . How we can change the text color of edittext in Android Searchview using AndroidX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The searchView below is the reference variable of Searchview you are using .

**JAVA:**

```
    EditText editText = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    editText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    editText.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

**KOTLIN**

```
val editText = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
editText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically if you wish and which is a pretty  good trick, well I am telling you how to do it in XML:

1. Go to your color.xml file which is in values under resources.
2. You will find 3 colors defined there, Add  colors there let suppose blue and orange colors like this

   ```
   <color name="colorblue">#FF0A7FE4</color>
   <color name="colororange">#F76707</color>
   ```
3. Now got to the XML where you have that search box EditText
4. In that editText view add  attributes :

   ```
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorblue"
    android:textColor="@color/colororange"
   ```

   there you will find the hint color will be now changed to blue and the text color will now be orange.